# in ember-data, when in the lifecycle is a newly created record's id available?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

using the RESTAdapter in ember-data.  i create a record on the server, and i need to get the id of the newly created record.  that id gets passed back from the server, i can see it in the json returned.

however, in the DS.Model's didCreate() callback, this.get('id') is undefined.

i also tried adding a record.one('didCreate',aClass,aClass.onDidCreate) and checking newRecord.get('id') but it's also undefined.

the didCommit callback doesn't seem to get called after createRecord() , so i'm not sure where else i should be checking in the lifecycle callbacks.  anyone know?

Comment: This seems like the returned json does not fit with the RESTAdapter. could you post it please ?

Comment: @sly7_2 i don't think that's the issue, but here's the JSON:  {"track":{"width":-1,"height":-1,"name":"5dplusgrip.jpg","id":270,"asset_id":295}}

Comment: Ok, right, the JSON seems ok. Could you post more context then ? for example the model, how you do the request, the store/adapter code... You could also wrap newRecord.get('id') inside a Ember.run.next(), inside you didCreate callback.

Comment: I think this is a bug discussed in https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/405

Comment: thanks for the confirmation pangratz. for the time being i created a mixin that does the addObserver() in the answer below, and i fire a custom action on the model, 'idWasCreated'.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the hook is for the returned id, but I've been setting an observer on 'id' to fire a method like so:

`record.addObserver('id', this, 'actionToFire');`

That seems to do the trick.

**Update:** Remember to `removeObserver` in `actionToFire` though so they don't pile up!